# Animate CardView to grow when child recyclerview changes size

Tags: android

I have a CardView and there is a RecyclerView inside of it which dynamically changes content.

It looks like this

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7duX.png)

I but that happens abruptly. I'd like the parent CardView to change size as shown in this gif. How can I do this?

[Animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDK0I.gif)